# Как вместо cmd сделать PowerShell Windows 10?

Tags: cmd, windows-10, powershell

Появилась проблема, почему-то, когда нажимаю <kbd>Shift</kbd> + ПКМ в нужной мне папке могу открыть только обычную консоль cmd, а мне нужно именно PowerShell. Раньше был PowerShell, потом долго не работал с ним, а теперь у меня cmd, ну, видимо,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я что-то наклацал:) Помогите пожалуйста :D

Comment: Гляньте https://remontka.pro/open-command-window-windows-10/ Там в конце получают оба пункта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

я вспомнил, что в Visual Studio Code(я там работаю) есть возможность создать терминал, один из которых и есть powershell, открываеться сразу в нужной мне папке, так что, уже всё нормально.